# Ensure an application starts logged as a user in a server

Tags: windows-server-2008, process

I need to ensure an application run on a server alway, as a service do, but for [some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688555/viewport3d-rendering-from-a-windows-service) I can't create a real window service. I would like to have this app running as an user with its own desktop ( not in Session0 ). I know this is kind of worst practice, but I've no other solution. What's the best way in achieving this?

Comment: I say this with all kindness; when you say "I know this is the worst practice, but..." you're already setting yourself up for a major headaches.  Is virtualization an option? I.e. have a virtual host running on the server, to do the one job that it needs to do?

Comment: @Stephan: It would be nice not to have to deal with software like this, but it's a sad reality. I have multiple Customer sites where deal with brain-damaged applications like these. It's a roaring pain but something that, as sysadmins, we are often not in control of (don't have source code for the software, can't convince the business to use some other program, etc). Likewise, you may not have the budget or influence to demand the purchase of additional operating system licenses to run the software in a dedicated VM. I like to do things the best way, but sometimes that's not possible.

Comment: @EvanAnderson I could possibly have influence to buy a license, but how this would help me ? Please advice...

Comment: @EvanAnderson software is mine :) I trust it by a security point of view, this is a major drawback but it really save my soul having it working.

Comment: @FelicePollano: The "buy a license" was suggesting that you run a freestanding operating system a a VM with the software running on the console of that VM. This was primarily a response to Stephan's statement "have a virtual host running on the server".

Comment: @EvanAnderson ok I think this answer deserve the check, but how to auto-logon the VM? As you see I'm a poor developer and I need to know even basic stuff in System engineering :)

Comment: @FelicePollano: You could use the same "AutoAdminLogon" functionality that I make reference to in my answer to make a Windows virtual machine logon automatically. I'll drop on an edit with references at Microsoft's site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an ugly, quick-and-dirty, *insecure* (and probably inadvisable) solution:

- Configure the server computer with an [`AutoAdminLogon`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324737) as some user with interactive logon capability. Let's call this user "user1".
- While logged on as that user, create an .RDP file to logon to the server computer and save the credentials for the user account that will host the application you want to run in Terminal Services. Let's call this user "user2".
- Save the .RDP file into the "user1" "Startup" program group.
- Save a shortcut to the application you need to start in the "user2" "Startup" program group.
- Add a shortcut to the both the "user1" and "user2" "Startup" program groups to execute `rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation` to lock the workstation immediately after logon.

When the server boots it will logon as "user1", start the Terminal Services client with saved credentials for "user2", and lock the workstation. The Terminal Services client will logon "user2", start the application you intend to run on its own Session, and then lock the workstation.

This kinda makes me feel dirty.

Comment: +1 for "This kinda makes me feel dirty."

Also ... for when you absolutely positively have to hack the hell out of it.